# Spring security login is still coming even after I used permit all

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am very new to spring security. I am building a project which has login logout feature. I did the configuration as told in the tutorials but is still not allowing to access directly without login.
And most of the methods which i use says that it is marked for
deprecated or marked for removal.
I will be grateful if anyone can guide me

I also noticed that it is not generating the default username and password for login

```
package com.example.covidsurvey.config;

import org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityConfig;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MyConfig {
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService getUserDetailServices() {
        return new UserDetailServiceImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(this.getUserDetailServices());
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/admin/**").permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("/user/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin();


        return httpSecurity.build();

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

im not sure what url you want to hit but i believe `.authenticated()` is causing spring to want to authenticate you

i would say to check out [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57578627/22080520), they do a good job explaining how to enable/disable security for specific endpoints

hope this helps